# writeSync() only writes to the console when console.log is present (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Take the following snippet:

```
try {
      fs = require('fs');
      fs.writeSync(0, 'Trying now...');
      fs.writeSync(0, 'worked!\r');
    }
catch(error){}
```

As is, it will not output to the console, however

```
  try {
  fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeSync(0, 'Trying now...');
  fs.writeSync(0, 'worked!\r');
  console.log();
}
catch(error){}
```

Will output "Trying now... worked!" to the console. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Can you try replacing `\r` with `\n`?

Comment: Just tried that and it worked. Didn't realize carriage returns meant nothing to Unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing to the file descriptor but are not flushing it. Writing a line break (`\n` instead of `\r`) does lead to stdout flushing its buffer, as well as a `console.log()` call that forces it.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized it was because I was using \r instead of \n